# Is kloxo secure?

Tags: vps

I have installed kloxo/lxadmin in my VPS,
I'm wondering is kloxo, lxadmin secure or will it get my vps hacked?

Answer (score 3):

Kloxo had [major vulnerabilities exposed](http://secunia.com/advisories/35337/) last year, which resulted in a very personal tragedy - [the then developer of Kloxo/HyperVM took his own life](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/06/09/lxlabs_funder_death/).

Since then, the product has been open-sourced and a check of the forums suggests that the major vulnerabilities have in fact been [fixed](http://forum.lxcenter.org/index.php?t=msg&th=12957&start=0&).

After that particular incident however, I'm very wary of using Kloxo so I'd recommend looking at other options such as Cpanel (if available) for providing a Web-based administrative interface. If you are limited to using Kloxo, I'd suggest starting off by looking at [the Security sub-forum](http://forum.lxcenter.org/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=44&) on LxCenter and articles like [this](http://wiki.lxcenter.org/How+to+secure+your+Kloxo+with+IPTABLES) on the [LxWiki](http://wiki.lxcenter.org/tiki-index.php).

Comment: CPanel is not for free, however, kloxo is open sourced, so it should be more secure, if lots of people read its code:)